# Difference between -> and ::

Tags: php, oop

What is the difference between :: and -> in php

For example

```
class hi{
public function bye(){
echo 'bye';
}
}

$hi = new Hi();

$hi::hi();
$hi -> hi();
```

Answer (score 1):

`->` is for a method of a class instance. `::` is for a static class method.